# Generally, how does one interpret the probabilities produced by a multi-label classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability

Most things I've seen just use the max probability, which seems alright, but doesn't give you any indication of confidence. The relative probabilities should be important too, right? Let me explain:

In the case of a binary classifier, suppose your categories are A and B.

P(A) = 0.01, P(B) = 0.99 is a classification result that very strongly indicates 'A'.

P(A) = 0.6, P(B) = 0.4 is a less confident 'A' classification.

Once you throw category 'C' into the mix, you could get
P(A) = 0.8, P(B) = 0.1, P(C) = 0.1, which is strongly 'A'

You could also, however, get one of the following:

1. P(A) = 0.50, P(B) = 0.25, P(C) = 0.25
2. P(A) = 0.50, P(B) = 0.49, P(C) = 0.01

Now, the first case is less confident, but would still come up 'A'
If max was my only criteria, the second case would be exactly the same, but clearly its not.

In case 1, 'A' isn't that confident of a result, but there's nothing else its likely to be. In case 2, P(A) is still 0.5, but its basically the same as P(B), meaning I shouldn't really have any faith in the observation being an 'A'

Is there a function which would capture this notion of relative confidence? I've been trying to think up a solution which isn't a cludgy collection of if-statements, but haven't come up with anything good.

Comment: In both cases P(A) = 0.5, so your 'faith' in the observation being an 'A' is the same.

Comment: In a probability sense, I'd agree. Does it make sense to interpret classification results as purely probabilities? Intuitively, I see it as the classifier saying "if I have to choose, A is the most likely candidate" in the first case, and being unable to distiguish between A and B in the second case

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not all classifiers are probabilistic classifiers. Unless we know a bit about the underlying model, this is not possible to answer. If you use a method that produces distorted probabilities, you will need to calibrate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration_(statistics)#In_classification). As @Tchotchke mentions this is more appropriate for CV.

Comment: [This CrossValidated thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/158139/97330) has some info on translating probabilities to confidence measures.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably getting at is captured by the idea of Support Vector Machines. In SVM classifier, we aim to find the hyperplane that maximizes the distance between the closest examples from the two groups it is separating. For details please look into wikipedia's or any machine learning text on SVM. In this approach you classify things such that the boundary has the biggest margin.

For logistic regressions, we use Softmax function, which is not score(i)/Sum(Score all). It uses exponential function. This also maximizes the distances between probabilities.

In general though, the goal of classification algorithm is to give an answer, specially for situations which might be ambiguous. Sure you can throw in an extra attribute to say how much the exact probability was, but that is usually not the primary objective.